# All controls are still null after calling EnsureChildControls()?

Tags: asp.net, custom-controls, page-lifecycle

The way this page is laid out, all of the data is loaded at `Page_Init`. Well, I have a custom control that is having problems with this though.

I have it on the page like so:

```
<cc:SomeControl... />
```

And then I set the value at Page_Init using

```
MyControl.Value="blah";
```

Simple stuff..

The `Value` is an accessor and has something similar to this:

```
public string Value{
  get...
  set{
    EnsureChildControls();
    MyHiddenField.Value=value;
  }
}
```

and it is here that I have a problem. It says that `MyHiddenField` is null. Is `Page_Init` just too early for this? Or is there some other function I need to call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix for this was changing from using a namespace to reference the CustomControl to using a `src` with a filename

changing this:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="MyProduct" Namespace="MyProduct.CustomControls" TagPrefix="cc" %>
```

to this:

```
<%@ Register src="/CustomControls/MyControl.ascx" tagname="MyControl" tagprefix="uc2" %>
```